# PyQt QToolBar with scrollbar

Tags: scroll, pyqt, toolbar

I need to create a toolbar (on the left side for example) that will contain many buttons. On default if overall height of all buttons is greater than the hight of toolbar these surplus buttons will be hidden. And I want to make this toolbar show all buttons and allow me to scroll down to see the rest. I couldn't find anything usefull on the web so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone interested here is the solution:

Thanks to @Brendan Abel's answer I've came up with an idea. What I did is I've created my toolbar the same way I did before. Then I've added all my widgets (that previously were in this toolbar) to the new QWidget with QVBoxLayout. Then I've created a QScrollArea and set my recently-created-widget as a child widget of this scroll area. And finally I've added my ScrollArea to the Toolbar using addWidget().

```
class LeftToolbar(QtGui.QToolBar):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QToolBar.__init__(self, *args)
        self.setFloatable(False)
        self.setMovable(False)

        self.scroll_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.scroll_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.scroll_widget.setLayout(self.scroll_layout)

        # Add your toolbar widgets here
        self.ExampleWidget1 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.ExampleWidget1.setText("Example Text1")
        self.scroll_layout.addWidget(self.ExampleWidget1)

        self.ExampleWidget2 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.ExampleWidget2.setText("Example Text2")
        self.scroll_layout.addWidget(self.ExampleWidget2)

        # Create QScrollArea
        self.scroll_area = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.scroll_widget)
        self.addWidget(self.scroll_area)

# Create object LeftToolbar in your main window
self.LeftToolbar = LeftToolbar()
self.addToolBar(Qt.LeftToolBarArea, self.LeftToolbar)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to stick the `QToolBar` inside a `QScrollArea`.

```
toolbar = QtGui.QToolBar()
toolbar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
for i in range(20):
    toolbar.addAction('Action{0}'.format(i))
scroll_area = QtGui.QScrollArea()
scroll_area.setWidget(toolbar)
```